# WiFi drops occasionally, and is much slower than other devices

Tags: drivers, wireless, ideapad

This has been an issue ever since I received the laptop.

While other devices get 50mbps, my laptop gets 0.50mbps. Every ten minutes or so, the WiFi completely drops for 15-ish seconds.

I believe this may be a driver issue. On the `Software & Updates` program, under the `Additional Drivers` tab, it says:

`Intel Corporation: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth`
`This device is not working.`

The only selectable check box is `Continue using a manually installed driver.`

Do I need to update my WiFi drivers, and if so, how would I do this? When I go to the Lenovo website, the driver only comes in a .exe file, which obviously I can't run with Ubuntu.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I am running 18.04.04 LTS. My kernal version is 5.4.0-42-generic.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release and or kernel version are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS. I also noticed that Settings says I am running a different processor (Ryzen 7) than what I have (Ryzen 5). Hmmm. Even the sticker says Ryzen 5.

Comment: Edit your question to add this. Actual kernel version is also useful (there are several possible kernels, "standard" or HWE for instance).

Comment: Done! My kernel version is 5.4.0-42-generic. Thank you